# Xcode iOS crash explain

Tags: xcode, crash

I have a crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<im.AppName.AppName-dev>:2443 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Background
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-update
WatchdogVisibility: Background
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.810 (user 1.040, system 0.770), 3% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.006, 0% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362dac4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e00a578 _dispatch_sema4_wait + 28
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e00ac2c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 132
3   AppName                                0x1005c66c0 0x100570000 + 353984
4   AppName                                0x1006b3394 0x100570000 + 1323924
5   UIKitCore                              0x198d904f0 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 204
6   UIKitCore                              0x198f32410 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitionsAllowingAnimation:actions:] + 140
7   UIKitCore                              0x198d91ddc -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 136
8   UIKitCore                              0x198d915c0 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke_2 + 652
9   UIKitCore                              0x198c8b600 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 108
10  UIKitCore                              0x198fcd918 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
11  UIKitCore                              0x198e7e014 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 332
12  UIKitCore                              0x198e7ddcc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 620
13  UIKitCore                              0x198e7d97c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252
14  UIKitCore                              0x198e7d848 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
15  UIKitCore                              0x19955ffa8 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
16  UIKitCore                              0x1995f8f98 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
17  UIKitCore                              0x198d29958 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
18  UIKitCore                              0x19919c7a8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.214 + 556
19  UIKitCore                              0x198dfc0b8 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216
20  UIKitCore                              0x198dfbf28 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
21  UIKitCore                              0x198dfbd68 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 336
22  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac655cdc -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 420
23  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac655b18 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 144
24  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac659294 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
25  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac6591b0 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 340
26  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e009fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
27  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e00da5c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac6633b0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac662f4c -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
30  FrontBoardServices                     0x1ac66572c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
31  CoreFoundation                         0x196b05f54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
32  CoreFoundation                         0x196b1232c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
33  CoreFoundation                         0x196a96210 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
34  CoreFoundation                         0x196aabba8 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
35  CoreFoundation                         0x196ab0ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
36  GraphicsServices                       0x1cfdae368 GSEventRunModal + 164
37  UIKitCore                              0x198f8f3d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
38  UIKitCore                              0x198f8f034 UIApplicationMain + 340
39  AppName                                0x1006b4438 0x100570000 + 1328184
40  dyld                                   0x1b5118960 start + 2528

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362db48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d3640008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d3640248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362e08c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x196aaaaf0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x196aabd34 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x196ab0ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x190e5a334 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x190e5a21c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1990c433c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 436
10  Foundation                             0x190e73808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a906cc _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362db48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d3640008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d3640248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362e08c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x196aaaaf0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x196aabd34 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x196ab0ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CFNetwork                              0x197e085a8 0x197bb2000 + 2450856
8   Foundation                             0x190e73808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a906cc _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:   Dispatch queue: com.AppName.response-queue
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d362e680 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e00a9cc _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e00ad7c _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 56
3   AppName                                0x1005c6cb0 0x100570000 + 355504
4   AppName                                0x1005c9510 0x100570000 + 365840
5   AppName                                0x100705cf0 0x100570000 + 1662192
6   AppName                                0x100732dc4 0x100570000 + 1846724
7   AppName                                0x1005a5614 0x100570000 + 218644
8   AppName                                0x1005a67d0 0x100570000 + 223184
9   AppName                                0x1005a4eb8 0x100570000 + 216760
10  AppName                                0x100c99344 0x100570000 + 7508804
11  AppName                                0x100c2e760 0x100570000 + 7071584
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e0084b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e009fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e011694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e0121e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e01ce10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fdf8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fb98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fb90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fb90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fb90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1e3a8fb90 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000000000000e   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x00000001ed09c1e8   x3: 0x0000000280c05510
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000002   x6: 0x0000001200000005   x7: 0x0000000000000002
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0xffffffffffffffff  x10: 0x00000001f4e3bf18  x11: 0x000000000000000f
   x12: 0x0000000000813d80  x13: 0x000000010289f390  x14: 0x00000001ed09c1e8  x15: 0x00000001ed09c1e8
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffdc  x17: 0x00000001f212d058  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000281830cc0
   x20: 0x0000000281830c80  x21: 0xffffffffffffffff  x22: 0x00000001005c4ecc  x23: 0x00000001ea401af0
   x24: 0x00000001006b2120  x25: 0x0000000101806b20  x26: 0x0000000281465580  x27: 0x0000000281501980
   x28: 0x000000028173b500   fp: 0x000000016f88d640   lr: 0x000000019e00a578
    sp: 0x000000016f88d630   pc: 0x00000001d362dac4 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x00000001ea5c8490  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1d362d000 -        0x1d3663ffb libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <ff27fc8f90ba3332ab7ac5bc2d9ca7b1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x19e006000 -        0x19e04cfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <fea36690a0003c55b7009120b05aa69b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x100570000 -        0x101013fff AppName arm64  <fb7380c17ab7349381ed8db80f753a1a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A8957E02-C3C1-4F5C-855B-51D0604297F1/AppName.app/AppName
       0x198bed000 -        0x19a3cafff UIKitCore arm64e  <179501b60fc2344ab969b4e3961ebe10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1ac652000 -        0x1ac6f7fff FrontBoardServices arm64e  <65e92d01137f3e1698a6a33706699695> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x196a30000 -        0x196e15fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <5cdc5d9ae5063740b64ebb30867b4f1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1cfdad000 -        0x1cfdb5fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <a633a095122639428f413877660185ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1b5103000 -        0x1b518600f dyld arm64e  <cb3ff411476234d286a4eca13f9fb6c3> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x190e18000 -        0x191761fff Foundation arm64e  <c431acb6fe043d28b6774de6e1c7d81f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1e3a8f000 -        0x1e3a9afff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <1aa3a4b6f9e730568c8b4e4dd81312a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x197bb2000 -        0x197f79fff CFNetwork arm64e  <edb0559fc996327f9b3a6616e316f24d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork

EOF
```

Could you please explain to me what happened? My understanding is that my app was in the background and the app wanted to update some UI in the main thread, but for some reason it failed, right? and the system killed my app after 10 seconds. But why can't the app update in the background?

As the user explained to me, he made a request to the server (which returns some data to show it in the app) and it took so long (probably internet problems). Then he hid the app and when he came back it went down in the background.

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log so you can see exactly where in your app the problem occurred.

Comment: Your app should not try to update UI in background. It can update the model and the UI may be updated when the system tells it it will enter foreground : [Preparing your UI to run in the foreground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_foreground)